# Multiple bibliographies using apacite - R Markdown to pdf)

Tags: pdf, latex, bookdown, bibliography

Novice here so apologise for my gross incompetence. Thanks in advance for any help or support you can offer.

I am using R bookdown to write my thesis, supplemented by some embedded latex to help prepare and format my pdf. It has gone quite well so far however I have now come across an issue that I just can't solve...

My thesis is split into two large sections and each section requires its own bibliography. I have seperate bib files for each bibliography. My problem is that I cannot manage to work out how to get the two bibliographies into my document (using apacite). I have had a look at the latex package documentation for apacite and bibunits but my attempts to follow there examples repeatedly do not work.

If anyone could post a working example of how to achieve this I would be eternally grateful!

Many thanks!